# Microsoft Bot Framework OAuth Card Returns Bad Request

Tags: .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have an `OAuthPrompt` prompting a user to Login in Microsoft Teams. Previously I had an issue where the Login button would not open an external link prompting the user with a manual login. This was solved by adding some information to the manifest, following this post: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/707. The issue that I am now facing is that certain users when attempting to login get a bad request after they type in their email and password. I'm not sure why this is happening. Could I get some information about which users this should work for? Perhaps it is because they are not owners of the web app bot? I am using Bot Framework SDK v4 if that matters.

Edit: The way that I am prompting the user with the built in `OAuthPrompt` is as follows:

```
    return new OAuthPrompt(
            "loginPrompt",
            new OAuthPromptSettings
            {
                ConnectionName = connectionName,
                Text = "Please login by pressing the button below...",
                Title = "Login",
                Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
            });
```

Here is how that renders in teams and the url it sends to:
[OAuthPrompt teams render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erwg7.png)

Comment: What did you set as the tenant ID's for your OAuth connection?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I'm not sure how to find the tenant ID. I'm going to edit my question to include information about the OAuthPrompt.

Comment: Did you set up an OAuth connection in your bot resource's settings in Azure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication

Comment: There are currently some restrictions to where you can use the OAuthCard in Microsoft Teams. It does not support Guest User, Microsoft Teams free users. Read more here: [Support for the OAuthCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-oauth-card#support-for-the-oauthcard).
Could you please confirm if it's freemium or guest user?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes, we have set up an OAuth connection. It works for two people in Teams, but no one else that we have tested with so far. Here it is: https://i.imgur.com/gsumAfE.png

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I have confirmed they are not Guest or Freemium users.

Comment: If you click on the connection in Azure you can see its settings including the tenant ID

Comment: @KyleDelaney It is set to 'common' right now.

Comment: Can you share the Sign In URL? Open Teams in web client, now when you click on sign in button it openes up a pop-up window. You should be able to see the sign in URL in address bar of a pop-up. It starts with - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.....

Comment: I'm not sure what changed but this started working for all users - no longer getting BadRequest. Thank you guys.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue? I am facing the same problem (but i am getting the bad request in bot emulator). Additionally, after I get the "Bad Request" message in the authentication window, processing of the bot stops. I am authenticated anyway, because when I start the same action in the bot, I get a token.

Comment: @craigbot - Go ahead and post an answer to say this has been resolved

Comment: Actually, funny enough once I updated my code using the v4.4 codebase `.\BotBuilder-Samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\46.teams-auth`, the OAuthPrompt is returning a BadRequest in the window that opens again within emulator. Going to do some digging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the OAuth setting that I set up in the portal disappeared and so the name for the `connectionName` within the OAuthPrompt wasn't referencing an actual connection name. To fix this, I went into the web app bot -> settings, and added a new setting under OAuth Connection Settings.